# disable updatedAt (update date) field in sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

I used `sequelize-auto` to generate schema, and I tried to use `findOne()` and I got this error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name
> 'updatedAt'.

in my database table, there is no field `updatedAt`.

for example, my table name is `Users` my code is `Users.findOne()`, and there is no `updatedAt` field in the `Users` table.

```
db.users= sequelize.import(__dirname + "/models/users");
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

  db.user.findOne().then(function (project) {
    res.json(project);
  })
  
});
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#configuration) for configuration of Model in Sequelize

In model object of your table should look like this.

```
var user = sequelize.define('user', { /* bla */ }, {

  // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
  timestamps: false,

  // If don't want createdAt
  createdAt: false,

  // If don't want updatedAt
  updatedAt: false,

  // your other configuration here

});
```

Check [Usage of sequelize-auto-generation](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) module

1. Create one json file for all model configuration options (flag object as defined [here](https://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sequelize/)).
2. When executing command you have to pass `-a` or `--addtional` option for that where you have to pass json file configuration path.

Comment: oh ya, i get it too, so we must add config options in sequelize-auto generation, can you help me how to add the config? i just try it but still fail

Comment: I have added some instructions in my answer

Comment: The question seems to be about disabling only the updatedAt, not both columns. It shoudn't be the accepted answer, I believe.

Comment: This approach should be the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248189/not-store-updatedat-with-sequelize-model

Comment: @RafaelCalhau Thanks for your attention.. I have changed my answer according to your concern.

Answer (score 1):

in Models => if you want to disable insert automatically createdAt, updatedAt use this

```
createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true, defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') },
updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: true, defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
```

in Services => if you want to to show only spesific column use this

```
async function getAll() {
    return await db.regencies.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'province_id', 'name']
    });
}
```