# Not store updatedAt with sequelize model

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

When I store models in my MySQL DB, they are immutable. As a result I can see the need for the createdAt column in my tables, but I don't need the redundant updatedAt column. Can I configure sequelize not to store updatedAt time and then can I drop the column from my table?

Comment: Isn't this just simply removing the column and removing cases where you are setting the data for that column?

Comment: Nope, it seems that when I set `timestamps: true` to the model, sequelize automatically creates and tries to use these columns.

Comment: oh sorry didn't realize you found the answer. glad things worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration, I should use `updatedAt: false` in my model definition.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the documentation regarding your situation

> If you want sequelize to handle timestamps, but only want some of them, or want your timestamps to be called something else, you can override each column individually:

```
const Foo = sequelize.define('foo',  { /* bla */ }, {
  // don't forget to enable timestamps!
  timestamps: true,

  // I don't want createdAt
  createdAt: false,

  // I want updatedAt to actually be called updateTimestamp
  updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp',

  // And deletedAt to be called destroyTime (remember to enable paranoid for this to work)
  deletedAt: 'destroyTime',
  paranoid: true
})
```

So in the above example, just set `timestamps` to be `true` but then `createdAt` to be false

Comment: Can we just disable updating updateAt for a specific query? (such as some jobs which update some summary fields on all instances)